# how to write a query where you get information based on the foreign key from a child table on ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I am writing a database where I have 3 tables to store data and the forth table to store the actual operations I am pulling the data from 2 tables based on its foreign keys(users and course tables) then I want to pull the college name based on the college Id from the course table. For instance, if the operations table the foreign key for the course Id = 1 I want to pull the name from the college table where the course Id = 1 on the course table.

The relationship:

[image]

This is the query to pull the data without the addition to pull the college name

```
SELECT First_Name, Second_Name, Last_Name, Course_Name, Date_Course, College_Name AS OperationDetails
FROM (Operations INNER JOIN Users ON Operations.User_id = Users.User_Id) INNER JOIN Courses ON 
Operations.course_Id = Courses.Course_Id;
```

I have tried to join the college table to pull the college name but I was not able any suggestion how to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need another join to `Colleges` like this:

```
SELECT Users.First_Name, Users.Second_Name, Users.Last_Name, 
       Courses.Course_Name, Courses.Date_Course, 
       Coleges.College_Name AS OperationDetails
FROM (
  (Operations INNER JOIN Users ON Operations.User_id = Users.User_Id) 
  INNER JOIN Courses ON Operations.course_Id = Courses.Course_Id
)
INNER JOIN Colleges ON Coleges.college_id = Courses.college_id;
```

This last join is based on `college_id` of the `Courses` table because you say: *I want to pull the name from the college table where the course Id = 1 on the course table*.
Also you should qualify all the column names with the table name/alias and in case like this where multiple tables are involved you should uses aliases to make the code shorter and more readable:

```
SELECT u.First_Name, u.Second_Name, u.Last_Name, 
       c.Course_Name, c.Date_Course, 
       g.College_Name AS OperationDetails
FROM (
  (Operations AS o INNER JOIN Users AS u ON o.User_id = u.User_Id) 
  INNER JOIN Courses AS c ON o.course_Id = c.Course_Id
)
INNER JOIN Colleges AS g ON g.college_id = c.college_id;
```